# Bind polymer input value to non-polymer input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

Is there any way to update a paper-input element based on a Javascript/jQuery function? I can get the old input to update via clicking the link but I can't seem to figure out how to bind the old input value to the new paper-input value or simply update the new paper-input value with a regular function.

```
<!-- polymer element loads in shadow DOM -->
<my-form>
  <paper-input id="id1" name='id1' value="{{val1}}" onmouseover="this.value=getId1Value();"></paper input>
  <a href="#" onclick='myJavascriptFunction(1)' id='relativeValue1'>Subtract 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick='myJavascriptFunction(2)' id='relativeValue2'>Subtract 2</a>
</my-form>
<!-- end polymer element -->

<!--HTML input element in light DOM -->
<input type="text" id="id1" name="id1" value="{{val1}}" />
<!-- end HTML input element -->
```

Then here is the script and polymer info:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-form',
  properties: {
    val1: {
      type: String,
      value: getId1Value();
    }
  }
});
function getId1Value(){ return $$("#id1").val();}
function myJavascriptFunction(val){
  $$("[name='id1']").val(evaluate(val));//evaluate returns a calculation based on val)
}
```

Comment: If you try to use bindings? Maybe you can try to add some properties to `<my-form>` and then update in and bind directly to `<paper-input>` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what I had in mind, but to achieve the effect (syncing/binding multiple inputs), I used

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector('my-form::shadow #id1').value = myJavascriptFunction(1)">1</a>
```

and

```
function myJavascriptFunction(val){
  $$("[name='id1']").val(evaluate(val));//evaluate returns a calculation based on val)
  return evaluate(val);
}
```

In this instance, myJavascriptFunction not only set the old input value manually, but returned the value to be used in conjunction with the link onclick event. So my solution was targeting the shadow DOM with `document.querySelector()` and adjusting myJavascript function to set the old input value and return that same value.